# 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized error in Timer Publisher

Tags: swift, closures, combine

This is for MacOS. I am trying to encapsulate a Timer publisher into a class so I can have added functionality that is self contained. I have the following code

```
import Combine


class MyTimer{
    let subscription: AnyCancellable
    var count: Int = 0

    init(){
       subscription = Timer.publish(every:0.1,on:.main,in:.default).autoconnect()
          .sink{_ in
             self.count += 1
             print(self.count)
         }
    }

    deinit {
        subscription.cancel()     
        print("done")
    }

}
```

The class is called like so:

```
let timer = MyTimer()
```

And stopped by setting the timer to `nil`.

Unfortunately I get the

> 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized

error. If I remove the `count` bit in sink it works fine. I tried moving the `init` contents to a `start()` method and that worked but `deinit()` was never called when timer was set to `nil`. I am currently using a global for count as a work around but that isn't very satisfactory as more code will go into this class. Any hints how I can do this? I have looked at a few other similar questions but none seem to be relevant. Thanks!

Comment: The good approach would be to indeed move the contents of `init` to a `start()` or similar method. You just have to remember to capture `self` weakly in the closure - `{ [weak self] in ... }`. Your `deinit` isn't called because of a retain cycle, and capturing `self` weakly will resolve that.

Comment: Please don't put back the `swiftui` tag as it is completely irrelevant to this question. This question is purely about Combine, there's no SwiftUI code in it.

Comment: OK Thanks for your help! I figured it was a retain cycle that prevented deinit() being called. My next problem is that I am completely clueless with anything more than a simple closure at the moment so I am not sure how to write the [weak self] bit in sink. If I write:Could you show how that part would be written? Thanks!

Comment: Dávid Pásztor sorry! I didn't realise someone had removed it.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it, thanks to several posters. I moved the contents of init to a start() function like so:

```
class MyTimer{
    var subscription: AnyCancellable?
    var count: Int = 0


    init(){
    }

    func start(){
        subscription = Timer.publish(every:0.1, on:.main,     in:.default).autoconnect()
            . sink{ [weak self] _ in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    self.count += 1
                    print(self.count)
                }

    }

    deinit {
        subscription?.cancel()
        print("done")
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped

Comment: There's no need to call `subscription.cancel` in your `deinit`, Combine does that automatically for you.